Resistor network with multiple sources: solve for v2, v3 and vx
Thevenin with series and parallels


Is this a homework question?
This problem is easier to solve if you convert all sources into Norton sources because all of them will be in parallel to the load resistor. Hint: you will have three Norton sources in parallel to the load.
